# Flutter: can't play aduio from AWS pre-signed url

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, just-audio

I am using a signed URL generated by AWS to stream an audio file in Flutter using just_audio plugin, but the url has no .mp3 extension so it throws an error.

how can I solve this problem?

the link is like the below

```
final url="https://d2oogf3dio531h.cloudfront.net/65577d97-9969-4043-8bc4-5f6bb973e3a9.mp3?Policy=eyAKICAgIlN0YXRlbWVudCI6IFt7IAogICAgICAiUmVzb3VyY2UiOiJodHRwczovL2Qyb29nZjNkaW81MzFoLmNsb3VkZ291cmNlSXAiOFRpbWUiOjgzNTc5ODN9CiAgICAgIH0gCiAgIH1dIAp9&Signature=Jc1d~yaNIW5C3StRtQe-EZtZhGvAK-JGh1cDF~CrVYBjbJSpz-hmiPjZwGJjKEGaLCaOeFJjIYGE~B7P0dm8PLfjb6eydfebNfdp5OMdrFio2HnGRsjqVcPuCDOKtjezYu3isWtt0AY-Tim6TBYvG9kuG3pPZa5L32zD4aFwPTmmahZko~byCc0ZBQJbKCyG4AcKnevCd2LaGjNGloprw__&Key-Pair-Id=K35S9ERGS425ZB";
```

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct?  The one you posted results in an error attempting to load it.

Comment: it is not actually a signed url it's just to show that it hasn't ".mp3" extension at the end of it

Comment: I very much doubt the issue is the URL literally doesn't end in .mp3, but if it is, you can just add something like `#.mp3`